# Creating a list column in a dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two `DataFrames`:

**df1:**

```
       node        ids
0   ab          [978]
1   bc          [978, 121]
```

**df2:**

```
       name        id
0   alpha          978
1   bravo          121
```

I would like to add a new column called *names* in **df1** where I get the list of names corresponding to ids column like this

```
   node            ids             names
0   ab            [978]            [alpha]
1   bc            [978, 121]       [alpha,bravo]
```

Would apprreciate help.

Comment: Is possible value not match?

Comment: sorry I dont really understand what you meant to ask.

Comment: I think e.g. first row `ab          [978]` ic changed to `ab          [10]` and `10` is no in `df2['id']`

Comment: No, it works fine. I'm accepting your answer. Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use if both `id` values are integers (or both strings, same types):

```
d = df2.set_index('id')['name'].to_dict()
df1['names'] = [[d.get(y) for y in x] for x in df1['ids']]
print (df1)
  node         ids           names
0   ab       [978]         [alpha]
1   bc  [978, 121]  [alpha, bravo]
```

If possible value in list not match value of `df2['id']` is replaced some no match value:

```
d = df2.set_index('id')['name'].to_dict()
df1['names'] = [[d.get(y, 'no match') for y in x] for x in df1['ids']]
print (df1)
  node         ids              names
0   ab   [978, 10]  [alpha, no match]
1   bc  [978, 121]     [alpha, bravo]
```

Or is possible omit this values:

```
d = df2.set_index('id')['name'].to_dict()
df1['names'] = [[d[y] for y in x if y in d.keys()] for x in df1['ids']]
print (df1)
  node         ids           names
0   ab   [978, 10]         [alpha]
1   bc  [978, 121]  [alpha, bravo]
```

Comment: if you are using the `get` method you do not really need the `if y in d.keys()`, right?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - yes, it depends what happens if no match

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - I add 2 possible ideas, thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

How about you try with this alternative solution?

```
df1 = (df1.reset_index()).merge(
        ((df1['ids'].explode().reset_index()).merge(
                df2,how='left',left_on='ids',right_on='id').groupby('index')['name','ids'].agg(
                        lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()),
                how='left',on='index').drop(
                        columns=['index','ids_y']).rename(
                                columns={'ids_x':'ids'})
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  node         ids            name
0   ab       [978]         [alpha]
1   bc  [978, 121]  [alpha, bravo]
```